# Leading zero in CSV on reopen

Tags: vba, csv, excel

I have txt file which looks like below

[image]

I am importing the txt file in excel using the method shown [here](http://www.upenn.edu/computing/da/bo/webi/qna/iv_csvLeadingZeros.html). Column Account is converted to text.

[image]

Once the data is imported, file looks like below.
I have a requirement to save the file as `csv` which is then imported by different system.

[image]

The problem is on reopen the csv file looks like below. The leading zero in account column disappears. I cannot add `'` in front of Account column cells bcoz the system does not accepts. What can be done to preserve the leading zero on csv open/ reopen ?

[image]
I m doing this all using vba

```
Sub createcsv()

    Dim fileName As String
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim wkb As Workbook

    lastrow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    'If lastrow < 6 Then lastrow = 6


    For i = lastrow To 3 Step -1

        If Cells(i, 4).Text = vbNullString Then
            Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
        ElseIf Trim(Cells(i, 4).Value) = "-" Then
            Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
        ElseIf Cells(i, 4).Value = 0 Then
            Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
        ElseIf CDbl(Cells(i, 4).Text) = 0 Then
            Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next


    lastrow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    'If lastrow < 6 Then lastrow = 6


    retval = InputBox("Please enter journal Id", Default:="G")
    Range("A3:A" & lastrow) = retval

    retval = InputBox("Please enter Date", Default:=Date)
    Range("B3:B" & lastrow) = retval

    retval = InputBox("Please enter description", Default:="Master entry")
    Range("E3:E" & lastrow) = retval


    Dim strVal As String
    strVal = InputBox("Please enter File Name", Default:="Data")

    filePath = CreateFolder(strVal)
    fileName = GetFileName(filePath)

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy
    Set wkb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set sht = wkb.Sheets("sheet1")

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wkb.SaveAs fileName:=filePath, FileFormat:=xlCSV

    sht.Cells.Clear
    importTxt wkb, filePath, fileName

    sht.Columns("A:A").NumberFormat = "General"
    sht.Columns("B:B").NumberFormat = "M/d/yyyy"
    sht.Columns("D:D").NumberFormat = "0.00"
    sht.Columns("E:E").NumberFormat = "General"


    wkb.SaveAs fileName:=Replace(filePath, ".txt", ".csv"), FileFormat:=xlCSV
    wkb.Close
    Set wkb = Nothing

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
err_rout:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub



Function CreateFolder(Optional strName As String = "Data") As String

    Dim fso As Object, MyFolder As String
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    MyFolder = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Reports"


    If fso.FolderExists(MyFolder) = False Then
        fso.CreateFolder (MyFolder)
    End If

    MyFolder = MyFolder & "\" & Format(Now(), "MMM_YYYY")

    If fso.FolderExists(MyFolder) = False Then
        fso.CreateFolder (MyFolder)
    End If

    CreateFolder = MyFolder & "\" & strName & Format(Now(), "DD-MM-YY hh.mm.ss") & ".txt"
    Set fso = Nothing

End Function

Sub importTxt(ByRef wkb As Workbook, ByVal txtLink As String, ByVal fileName As String)

    With wkb.Sheets(fileName).QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
                                              "TEXT;" & txtLink, _
                                              Destination:=Range("$A$2"))
        .Name = fileName
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub

Function GetFileName(ByVal fullName As String, Optional pathSeparator As String = "\") As String
'?sheet1.GetFileName( "C:\Users\Santosh\Desktop\ssss.xlsx","\")

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim tempStr As String
    Dim iFNLenght As Integer
    iFNLenght = Len(fullName)

    For i = iFNLenght To 1 Step -1
        If Mid(fullName, i, 1) = pathSeparator Then Exit For
    Next

    tempStr = Right(fullName, iFNLenght - i)
    GetFileName = Left(tempStr, Len(tempStr) - 4)

End Function
```

Comment: What version of Excel are you using ? In Excel 2007 I just imported a file, with the account column as text. The leading zeros came in fine, I then saved as CSV and loaded the CSV into Notepad and the leading zeros where still there.

Comment: I am using excel 2010 and i am saving the file as CSV and opening it again.

Comment: When you say "opening it again" are you going through the data import process again, or just file>open ? File Open will loose the formatting.

Comment: No, once the csv file is created i pass on this file to another user. When he opens the csv to view the data leading zeros not there so data is incorrect.

Comment: @Santosh beacuse it is identical to your question - which has been asked many times before.

Comment: @brettdj you changed the link. Still you need to read my question and the existing link you gave carefully and then mark it as duplicate.

Comment: Sorry, I can't recreate your issue, it works fine for me.

Comment: @santosh. No I added a second link which is the same one I voted for as a duplicate. I removed the SuperUser comment, as the the duplicate link is more thorough. You should look more carefully before posting a widely asked question.

Comment: @user2465348  i have added the code with which i was creating a csv. Kindly refresh & let me know if you see any flaw.

Comment: I've run the code you've pasted and I still can't recreate your error, it exports with the leading zeros and re-imports back with the leading zeros.

Comment: @user2465348 So far its ok. But once i open the csv created the leading zero vanishes.

Comment: **STOP HELPING ME MICROSOFT!** If I don't want a leading zero ***I'll*** remove them!

Answer (score 2):

This is an unfortunate problem in MS Excel. I could not find any way around this, except to change the format and use xls. I was supplying data to my desktop application from a csv file that could be edited by anyone. Unfortunately, the leading zero problem stayed despite various things I tried. The only reliable method I found was to have a !before the number !00101 so that it was accepted as a string. This was okay for the application(it could replace the ! with nothing), but still the human readability factor was affected.

Depending on your application and use, you might have to use a different format.